# Fuelphp's Oil refine migrate command is failing

Tags: fuelphp

after a clean install of Fuel, I set the database configuration in the app config file, but after I run oil refine migrate I get

```
fuelphp oil refine migrate Error - invalid data source name in COREPATH/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 87
```

this problem just started happening and I have no idea what's wrong. it's not the settings in the config file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when a connection couldn't be established. In some cases you'll need to have the the host set to `127.0.0.1`, this all depends on your dev setup.
 
If you're running MAMP you can also alias the MySQL socket like so:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

As the troubleshooting section describes sometimes you need to create the MySQL directory first:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/mysql
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problems as well, but I found out that it's caused by the missing PDO extension in php-cli.ini, I am using UniformServer, after I added that in the config it worked. You should check if you have config for php cli.

Comment: I love you. Just thought you should know.
For anyone that doesn't want to look for it:
C:\UniServer\usr\local\php\php-cli.ini

I added the line: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: @CharlesSmith +1 for making me laugh

Comment: I'm using UniServer too and it's exactly the problem I got. Fixed it after trying you solution.